# How do I divide a single, large git branch into two successive branches?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I have some branches in git that look like:

```
master             b1
↓                   ↓ 
A -- B -- C -- D -- E
```

But `D ... E` turned out to be an unexpectedly nontrivial change, so I would like to see this instead:

```
master    b3
↓         ↓
A -- B -- C      b2
           \     ↓
            D -- E
```

...so that `b2` can be reviewed separately, merged into `b3`, which is then merged to master.

I tried:

```
git checkout b1
git checkout -b b2
git rebase C
```

but got merge conflicts. That indicates to me that's that wrong way to do it, since `C ... D` were all applied successively to each other and should never conflict. What incantation do I need?

Answer (score 3):

`b2` is equivalent to `b1`, so all you had to do was create `b3` on commit `C`.

```
git branch b3 C
```

If you insist that `b2` exists on commit `E` (in addition to `b1`) you can also just create it:

```
git branch b2 E
```

All commits in your second graph are identical to the first graph, so you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: That makes sense. After trying it, I didn't get what I expected from GitHub (and maybe it's a GitHub specific problem)— A PR from `b2` to `b3` shows all the commits from `A ... E` instead of `C ... E` as I would expect. Is something extra that needs to be done to the repository, or should I chalk it up to a neglected UX corner case in GH?

Comment: @trbabb When you want to submit `b2` as a PR that does not include `A`, `B`, or `C`, then you no longer have "two successive branches", but two "parallel" (so to speak) branches. Which one is it that you need?

Comment: I want to submit `b2` as a PR to `b3` (not master— yet), so the incremental changes aren't so large. Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As [mkrieger1 said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66993224/1256452), you literally just want to create the label `b3` pointing to commit `C`.

The trick with GitHub and GitHub's "PR"s (pull requests) is that now that you have these names *locally*, you need to create the *same names* on GitHub—remember that their repository is in fact a separate, independent repository, with its own independent branch names—pointing to the same hash IDs.  That part is easy enough: just `git push origin b3` with name `b3` identifying commit `C` locally.  Since commit `C` (with that same hash ID) is already copied to GitHub, this just creates the name `b3` *on* GitHub, pointing to commit `C`.  And, that now means that on GitHub, you can create a pull request that says *let's merge commit E into commit C, using names `b3` as the PR and `b2` as the "base branch"*.  GitHub can only see their own names in their own repositories, but now that you did the `git push`, they have the same names you do.

Note that if and when the PR is approved and commit `E` gets merged into commit `C` on GitHub, this can:

- be a true merge, or
- be a "rebase-and-merge", or
- be a "squash-and-merge"

but under no circumstances will the big green "merge" button on the GitHub web page create a *fast-forward* merge.  This means you will get:

```
master             b3
↓                  ↓
A -- B -- C ------ M
           \      /
            D -- E
                 ↑
                 b2
```

if you select the "true merge" option, or:

```
master                 b3
↓                      ↓
A -- B -- C ---- D' -- E'
           \
            D -- E
                 ↑
                 b2
```

if you select the rebase-and-merge option, or:

```
master            b3
↓                 ↓
A -- B -- C ---- DE
           \
            D -- E
                 ↑
                 b2
```

if you select the "squash and merge" option.

If none of those options are acceptable (for whatever reasons—they'd be *your* reasons since at least some of these should work in at least *some* circumstances), do not use the big green <kbd>merge</kbd> button on the GitHub web pages.